# Spring Transaction - when no exception thrown

Tags: spring

```
@Transactional
 method() {

  try {
       update1()
       update2()
      }
  catch (Exception ex) {
    // creating a response with error message and error code object        
  }

  return response ( contains response details for update1() and update2() )
}
```

I need some help with rolling back the transaction happened in  update1() when update2() failed.

When update1() fails the code works fine as we have not reached update2()
But when update1() is success and update2() fails, i catch the exception to create a response object, throwing an exception here in catch block is not an option as i need to create a response object... in this scenario .. update1 with status 201 and update2 with status 500 say.. over all status 500..

Help please...

Answer (score 0):

One solution that i have just found is as below, which worked for me.
Please let me know if there is an alternate to this solution. thanks

http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html

adding below in my catch block

```
TransactionAspectSupport.currentTransactionStatus().setRollbackOnly();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get more fine grained transactions using `TransactionTemplate`.

```
TransactionTemplate tt = new TransactionTemplate(tx);
tt.execute(new TransactionCallbackWithoutResult(){
   @Override 
   protected void doInTransactionWithoutResult(TransactionStatus status){
     ...
   }
}
```

You don't need to throw an exception to rollback. With `TransactionStatus` you can call `setRollbackOnly` to inform the transaction that the only possible outcome is a rollback.